# How do I get an 8 (or higher scores in general) on Clozemaster?

Tags: gamification, clozemaster

On [clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com) I can get extra points for typing instead of answering 1, 2, 3, or 4 for the multiple choice questions, but within those multiple choice questions, sometimes I'm awarded 4 points sometimes 8.

How do I get 8 points, and are there any other controllable factors to get more points for a single question?

- Clozemaster is a language learning website, similar to Duolingo, Ankiweb or Memrise. The difference is that it presents questions in the form of "fill in the blank". Source data comes from Tatoeba.

Comment: Could you add some information on what clozemaster is and how it works? I think some people on this site may not be familiar with it.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this; could you post a screenshot when this happens?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. You after you answer the same question correctly four times it is recored as "mastered". You get 8 points when the question goes from 15% mastered to 50% mastered.

So 8 points are awarded to correct review questions. I haven't played long enough to see if you get even more points for going from 50% to 75% mastered.

As a side note on strategy:

You get more points for answering faster. The 2x bonus for answering by typing the answer usually doesn't offset the points you lose because you are answering fewer questions. You can switch to "hint mode" which lets you get double points for things that are easy to type and get regular points for things that are hard to type for a much smaller time penalty.

Answer (score 1):

After scouring the Internet for answers, I still haven't been able to find any definitive answers as to why this is occurring. I actually tried Clozemaster, and played around it with it for about an hour, but  I still haven't been able to reproduce your problem.

When you pause in the middle of a lesson, this is the message the website has:

> Cloze mastery score multiplier is 8 for text input vs. 4 for multiple choice. Text input is more difficult than multiple choice, so you score more points! Switching to text input will also start a new round.

The only reason I might find for you getting 8 points on a multiple choice question is due to a bug that counts your multiple choice question as a text input question. I'd suggest filing a bug report [here](https://www.clozemaster.com/contact).

Comment: Very plausible that it is random- after all, it aims to gameify language learning, in this case, maybe by making it like a slot machine with variable rewards.

Comment: @MatthewMartin That's a good point. I still haven't found any reference of this phenomenon occurring anywhere else on the Internet, oddly enough.